# Zigzag vs direct map in rational homotopy theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rational-homotopy-theory

I was reading these notions from "Rational Homotopy Theory" by Felix, Halperin, and Thomas.

The notion of weak homotopy type is as follows: two spaces $X$ and $Y$ are said to be weak homotopy type if there is a zigzag of weak homotopy equivalences i.e., there is a sequence $$X\to Z_0 \leftarrow \cdots \to Z_k\leftarrow Y$$ with each arrow a weak homotopy equivalence.

The notion of weak equivalence for commutative cochain algebras is also similarly defined.

Motivated from above one may define the notion of rational homotopy type in a similar fashion. Two simply connected spaces $A$ and $B$ are said to be of rational homotopy type if there is a zigzag of rational homotopy equivalences i.e., there is a sequence $$A\to U_0 \leftarrow \cdots \to U_k\leftarrow B$$ with each arrow a rational homotopy equivalence (each arrow is a quasi-isomorphism).

I am not able to get a nontrivial example of two spaces having the same rational homotopy type. I want two simply connected spaces, with rational cohomology finite type, with no direct arrow that is a quasi-isomorphism but connected by a zigzag of rational homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Take distinct primes $p,q$ and consider $X=K(\mathbb{Z}_{(p)},n)$ and $Y=K(\mathbb{Z}_{(q)},n)$ with $n>1$ odd, where $A_{(p)}$ denotes the localisation of an abelian group $A$ at the prime $p$.